# Compare several strings in combine with NOT EQUAL / OR

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to compare following string:

```
read -p "Enter Application Name (abc / def )" app
if [ -z "$app" ] || [ $app != "abc" ] || [ $app != "def" ]; then
    echo "No or invalid application name entered"
    exit 1
fi
```

If you enter abc, the script is exited. According to the compare that should not happen, cause app is in this case "abc". Whats wrong here?

I tried it also with double brackets `[[ ]]` and with quotes `"$app" != "abc"`. Didn't work.

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confusing between logical test operators (`-a -o etc.`) and exit status operator (`&& and ||`).

What's happening with your script is the following:

1. `[ -z "$app" ] ||`  => if the `$app` variable is empty then the test returns `true`, but if it's not empty then the test returns `false` triggering the right part of the `||` operator.
2. `[ $app != "abc" ] ||` => if the `$app` variable is **not** 'abc'  the test returns `true`, but if **it's 'abc'** the test returns `false` **triggering the right part of the `||`** operator.
3. `[ $app != "def" ]` is then tested and returns `true` as `$app` is 'abc' and not 'def', thus echoing the message and exiting the script.

What you intend to do was in fact:

```sh
read -p "Enter Application Name (abc / def )" app
if [ -z "${app}" -o "${app}" != "abc" -a "${app}" != "def" ]; then
    echo "No or invalid application name entered"
    exit 1
fi
```

Take care to 'box' your shell variables with quotes and brackets (aka curly braces) in tests. And not only in tests.

**EDIT:** If you want to do that with exit status test operator then you should have done it like that :

```sh
read -p "Enter Application Name (abc / def )" app
if [ "${app}" != "abc" ] && [ "${app}" != "def" ]; then
    echo "No or invalid application name entered"
    exit 1
fi
```

As suggested by @chepner, you can use bash syntax and operators with the `[[ .. ]]` :

```sh
read -p "Enter Application Name (abc / def )" app
if [[ -z "${app}" || "${app}" != "abc" && "${app}" != "def" ]]; then
    echo "No or invalid application name entered"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `-a` and `-o` are non-standard and should not be used. Stick with `||` and `&&` (though you need to take care because they have *equal* precedence in shell). If you are using `[[`, you can safely use `[[ ... || ... && ... ]]`; the comparison operators *do* have the expected precedences for boolean operators.

Comment: @chepner You are right, i'm too used to old POSIX. I'll edit to add the bash corresponding script.